# CSS only being applied if put it in a certain stylesheet

Tags: css, google-chrome

For some reason, when I put this CSS code into `about.css` it works, but when I put it in the `theme.css` it doesn't work.

### CSS code that's not working:

```
.photo-credits p {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #FDFF33;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Paintball</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Styling--->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.css" />
    <!--Page Styling-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/about.css" />
    <!--Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
    <?php include("../html/navbar.php"); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Paintball </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="photo-credits">
            <p>PC: Name</p>
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

I don't understand why b/c as you can see on the JSFiddle, if I put the css from `about.css` and `theme.css` in one css file it works.

This has happened before (where it works when I paste all my CSS in JSFiddle) and it's really frustrating b/c I don't want to repeat code, but it seems that I may have to. Any advice on this would be really appreciated!

PS: I almost think it might be MAMP and maybe refreshing on Chrome. B/c I had another incident, where I unlinked the stylesheet, saved on Brackets, refreshed Chrome, then linked the stylesheet again, saved on Brackets, and refreshed on Chrome, and then suddenly the CSS I had added was applied.

### Using:

- MAMP
- PHP 5
- Brackets text editor

```css
/*theme.css*/
body {
    font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background-color: #0C0F0A;
    color: #F0F7F4;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #0C0F0A;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar li {
    float: left;
}

.navbar li a {
    display: block;
    color: #F0F7F4;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #F0F7F4;
    color: #0C0F0A;
}

.container {
    margin-top: 82px;
}

.photo-credits p {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #FDFF33;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/*about.css*/
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url('../images/Team%20Winter.png');
}

.title {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 550%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #F0F7F4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Paintball</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--Styling--->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/theme.css" />
    <!--Page Styling-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/about.css" />
    <!--Google fonts-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Narrow:400,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,400i" rel="stylesheet"> </head>

<body>
    <?php include("../html/navbar.php"); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title">Paintball </div>
        </div>
        <footer class="photo-credits">
            <p>PC: Name</p>
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually nvm! I realized the culprit was Chrome. Pressing `shift` + `command` + `R` refreshed the page and then my CSS styling was applied